# Tastypie for mongoengine in Django 1.9+

Tags: django, tastypie, mongoengine, django-1.9

Can you suggest any python-django library that allows serving mongoengine model data from tastypie. 
[django-tastypie-mongoengine](https://github.com/wlanslovenija/django-tastypie-mongoengine) is obsolete & now unmaintained and throws error with Django 1.9, but works fine with django 1.8.

Following is my django environment:

- Django 1.9.7
- mongoengine 0.10.6
- pymongo 3.2.2
- django-tastypie 0.13.3
- django-tastypie-mongoengine 0.4.6

Following were the errors encountered and fix made:

> 1. Initial compile error relating to deprecation of 'SortedDict'.
>      Fix: replaced 'SortedDict' with 'OrderedDict' (collections.OrderedDict)
> 2. Compile Error: AttributeError: 'StringField' object has no attribute 'help_text' (Line:727)
>      Fix: 'help_text': f.help_text  -->> 'help_text': getattr(f, 'help_text', ""),
> 3. Runtime error: Go to the resource url i.e. /app_name/api/resource_name/?format=json, throws error "TypeError:
>      unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'dict' and 'set'"

I am still confused on how to fix this, trying to trace back error to the source. Tastypie on django model works fine, the only issue is with mongoengine tastypie that too in django 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

I have made few changes in django-tastypie-mongoengine to make it compatible with django 1.9+ along with django-tastypie 0.13.3. I have forked a copy of the github repository and updated changes. It works fine now.
Following is the link:https://github.com/gagan144/django-tastypie-mongoengine